# Combine/consolidate entries in array

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a script that takes a snapshot of AD groups and check against current AD state for membership changes. It adds psobject to an array and outputs a table to a html file. the problem is i want to combine the results in the groups so it doesn't repeat user1 remove from group1, user2 remove from group1. The current output is:

```
object    action    group
user1     removed   group1
user2     removed   group1
userN     removed   groupN
```

I want the script to combine the entries so the output will be:

```
object    action    group
user1     removed   group1
user2     
userN     removed   groupN
```

Do you any idea how it would be done?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the Compare-Object function in powershell to check the two arrays.

An example of the compare-object function is:

```
PS> $shot1 = 1..10
PS> $shot2 = 10..1
PS> Compare-Object $shot1 $shot2

PS> $shot1 = 1..15
PS> $shot2 = 15..1
PS> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $shot1 -DifferenceObject $shot2

                                 InputObject SideIndicator
                                 ----------- -------------
                                          15 =>
                                           1 <=
                                          14 =>
                                           2 <=
                                           2 =>
                                           1 =>
                                          14 <=
                                          15 <=
```

The results indicate a property value appears only in the Reference set (indicated by <= ), only in the Difference set (indicated by => ) or in both objects (indicated by == when -IncludeEqual parameter is specified.)

Comment: `ForEach ($result in $results) {
    If ($result.SiteIndicator -eq "<=") {
       ...
       }
       elseif (...) {
       }
}`
This gives me a table with each result in new line.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. The above give me the result i posted in question. Then i want to process that and get it combined/consolidate to
`object    action    group
user1     removed   group1
user2     
userN     removed   groupN `